# Callback function's opposite results while updating database record

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

It's been few days that I have been trying to learn Codeigniter and while making small applications I came to this point where I have to update DB.

I have inserted data using validations but when it comes to updating, it looks like it is always "FALSE" as those records are already in DB that I am editing. Result, it doesn't take it.

Seeking some help here to overcome this problem.

Validation (Controller):

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules('v_member_email', 'Email Address', 'trim|required|valid_email|callback_check_if_email_exists');

    public function check_if_email_exists($requested_email) {
    $email_available = $this->update_model->check_if_email_exists($requested_email);
    if ($email_available) {
    return TRUE;
    } else {
    return FALSE;
    }}
```

It always returns "Validation Error" as this email is already in use.

Model:

```
function check_if_email_exists($email) {
$this->db->where('v_member_email', $email);
$result = $this->db->get('vbc_registered_members');
if ($result->num_rows() > 0){
return FALSE; //Email Taken
} else {
return TRUE; // Available
}}
```

Comment: Can you provide the code for `check_if_email_exists()` (from the `update_model` object?

Comment: Thanks @Ian, Code is there now.

Comment: You could use CI inbuilt form validation rule instead: `$this->form_validation->set_rules('v_member_email', 'Email Address', 'trim|required|valid_email|is_unique[vbc_registered_members.v_member_email]');`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, because, email is already present.

All you have to do is, pass the is to callback while updating like this,

```
callback_check_if_email_exists['.$id.']
```

Id is the database id.

In controller

```
public function check_if_email_exists($requested_email, $id) {
    $email_available = $this->update_model->check_if_email_exists($requested_email, $id);
    if ($email_available) {
        return TRUE;
    } else {
        return FALSE;
    }
}
```

In model

```
    if ($id) {
        $this->db->where('id !=', $id);
    }
    $this->db->where('email', $str);
    $res = $this->db->get('users');
    if ($res->num_rows()) {
        return false;
    } else {
        return true;
    }
}
```

What we are doing here is, if you are passing the id to callback, then

check if the email is present except this id,

If id is not passed, check only for email without considering the `id`

Comment: I have a small problem though. Since I have set form field value as value="<?php echo $user->v_member_email; ?>". Is there any way if there is a validation error, field value doesn't go back to and stay what was entered?

Answer (score 0):

in your controller you return true if the email exists. and false if not, but in your model you return false if exists and true if not.

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules('v_member_email', 'Email Address', 'trim|required|valid_email|callback_check_if_email_exists');

public function check_if_email_exists($requested_email) {
$email_available = $this->update_model->check_if_email_exists($requested_email);
// here you check if the return from the model is true or false if true the email exists otherwise the email not exists
if ($email_available) {
return TRUE; // here true mean the email is exists and not Available
} else {
return FALSE; // here it mean the email not exists and Available
}}
```

and that's the problem you should return true in your model if the email exists to make it work.

```
function check_if_email_exists($email) {
    $this->db->where('v_member_email', $email);
    $result = $this->db->get('vbc_registered_members');
    if ($result->num_rows() > 0){
        return true; // here true mean the email is exists and not Available
    } else {
        return false; // here it mean the email not exists and Available
    }
}
```

Comment: now you need to insert if the email not exists right ?

if so ... you need to insert if the return false from this 
if (!check_if_email_exists($requested_email)) {

insert...

}